# How to know the configuration et Platform of the program to write relative paths?

Tags: c++, configuration, platform, preprocessor-directive

I am writing a c++ code with Qt QML.
I have to specify some paths on folders situated in x64/Debug folders but I want my program to be as generic as possible so I would like to had some preprocessor instructions to know the configuration of the program (Release, Debug), the Platform (x86 or x64), the version of Qt I want... so I can chose the right path defined as a static const string.

I have no idea on how to do that, and don't know exactly what to search on the internet to do that...
Here's an example of path not generic enough for me:

```cpp
view.engine()->addImportPath(QStringLiteral("..\\..\\..\\..\\Tools\\Qt\\5.12.0\\x64\\5.12.0\\msvc2017_64\\qml"));
//or
#define QML_HOME "..\\ ..\\..\\..\\Tools\\Qt\\5.12.0\\x64\\5.12.0\\msvc2017_64\\qml"
```

thanks in advance